# secure at least 1 m from the floor?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I want to make a instruction for vertical ladder installation (Securing a ladder to a wall firmly with screws or something) Information I want to put in the sentence is:

1. Secure one spot (less than 0.5m from the floor) of the ladder to the wall
2. the rest of the part: every 1m

I don't know how to put these into a sentence...

- "Secure at least 0.5m from the floor and every 1m of the ladder to the fixture."
- "Secure one spot within 0.5m from the floor and every 1m of the ladder."

please help me. thank you.

Comment: *The bottom fixing must be at least 0.5m above the floor, and it must be secured every 1m above that.* I'd have thought it's implicit that you expect the lowest fixing to be no ***more*** than 1m above ground level, but perhaps you might think you should explicitly say that too.

Comment: Actually, your question text alternates between "at least" and "less than". I didn't think about the real-world implications before, but presumably you mean *The bottom fixing must be **no more than** 0.5m above the floor, and it must be secured every 1m above that.*

Comment: *At least* can be ambiguous: and depends on understanding what is being done and why. Normally it gives a minimum count or distance ("retreat at least 10 metres after lighting the firework"), but it can give an upper bound ("feed at least every 3 days").

Comment: Thank you  for answering. I understood that I shouldn't have used "at least" and I think "no more than 0.5 above the floor" is what I wanted to say.

Comment: Note that if it's an *outside* ladder, we'd say *...above [the] **ground***, not ***...floor.*** The article is optional with "ground", but *required* with "floor".

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot.

Comment: Don't try to explain in a written language.  **Draw a picture**